# Número de página en reporting services (ssrs)

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssrs

Buenas, estoy creando un informe con un índice de contenidos mediante reporting services (ssrs). Los datos de dicho índice provienen de una query personalizada y estan representados en una tabla de la siguiente manera:

1. Header1
   1.1 Header1.1
   1.2 Header1.2

Necesito añadir el número de página a cada fila pero no tengo ni idea de como hacerlo de manera dinámica (las únicas soluciones que he encontrado implican el uso de textbox estáticas para cada registro). Decir que soluciones como el "document mapping" no me valen ya que tengo que representar de manera bastante fiel un modelo de informe que tengo como referencia y dicha solución no me lo permite.

Un saludo y gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola Locke Wiggin. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. ¿Puedes mostrar lo que has intentado hasta ahora para que sobre tu codigo podamos ayudarte a mejorarlo?  Un saludo

Comment: Puedes hacer un dataset con esa query y agregarla en un textbox del tablix como valor, o podrias crear una expresion, podrias probar